# Why this jQuery code doesnt behave as expected?

Tags: jquery

Why is this query not working properly? Is the data-target attribute not able to identify another element?

**JS**

```
$('button').click(function(){
    // uses the button's "data-target" attribute to identify another element to toggle
    target = $('#' + $(this).data('target'));

    // toggles the visibility of the target
    if (target.is(':visible')) {
        target.slideUp();
    } else {
        target.slideDown();
    }

    // says goodbye if it was hidden 
    if (target.is(':hidden')){
        alert('goodbye, cruel world!');
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you recreate it in a fiddle? And please add the button markup, what is set in the data attribute, and is there a matching element?

Comment: Post HTML of buttons and its target markup

Comment: Works for me, fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/3dZHC/1/

Comment: make sure the value of `data-target` matches the element id

Comment: @user2748793 Is the issue that you are not getting the alert `alert('goodbye, cruel world!');` ??

Comment: Please explain "doesnt behave as expected"... what is the expected behavior and what is the actual behavior you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

Hers is jsfiddle with your example, http://jsfiddle.net/ravikumaranantha/sDvph/1/

this is nothing wrong with the code, could be problem with the markup, with below markup it works fine.

```
<button data-target="toggleTarget">test button</button>
<div id="toggleTarget">
    <p>this is the target</p>
    <p>this is the target</p>
    <p>this is the target</p>
    <p>this is the target</p>
    <p>this is the target</p>
    <p>this is the target</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically what doesn't work is your message when the target is hidden.

What happens here is that you check if the element is visible or not. However you use the .slideUp() to hide the element. *The element will not be seen as hidden when the animation hasn't completed.* You check if it's visible right after the animation is triggered (this doesn't mean the animation has completed). 
What you want to do is after the hide animation has completed show the message (You don't need to check if it's visible because it's always hidden after that animation)

```
if (target.is(':visible')) 
{
    target.slideUp('slow', function()
                   {
                       alert('goodbye, cruel world!');
                   });

} 
else 
{
    target.slideDown();
}
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ku5Wj/)**

Answer (score -1):

The data-attribute doesnt always give me what I want as result, that might be the problem. You can check if the value is correct:

```
console.log( $(this).data('target') );// check it's value
```

This works for sure:

```
target = $('#'+ $(this).attr('data-target') );
console.log( target.length +' items found'); // log how many items found (should be 1)
```

It's not the fact that you try to use the value of another object, a string is a string, no matter where it comes from (variable, property, value of attribute, etc)

Comment: I guess there is no difference

Comment: It's the other way around: `.attr('data-target')` doesn't always work if data has been added with `.data()`.